# gtest and libtorch undefined reference to `testing::internal::

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, libtorch

I am trying to use gtest with libtorch. Currently, I have a basic test program:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(WorldMapTests, FirstTest) {
    ASSERT_TRUE(true);
}
```

And then I have a main make where I get torch in the third-party folder as follows:

```
set(TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/libtorch")
set(Torch_DIR "${TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/cmake/Torch")
set(pybind11_INCLUDE_DIR "${TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/pybind11")
```

And then my test make looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(This ${PROJECT_NAME}_test)

set(Sources
  cpp/WorldMapTests.cpp
)


############################################################## gtest
# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)

--- SNIP --- (test configure stuff from the github)

endif()
############################################################## gtest




add_executable(${This} ${Sources})

target_link_libraries(${This} PUBLIC
    ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}
    gtest
    gtest_main
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
)

target_include_directories(${This} PUBLIC ${TORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_options(${This} PUBLIC ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS})

add_test(
    NAME ${This}
    COMMAND ${This}
)
```

When I compile in release version it is fine. It is also fine if I don't include "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}" in my link directory. However, when I link to torch and test under debug I get the following:

```
.../test/cpp/WorldMapTests.cpp:5: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GetBoolAssertionFailureMessage(testing::AssertionResult const&, char const*, char const*, char const*)'
```

I think it's because torch makes use of test and is compiled under a release build. I manually found a gtest.so in the lib folder under torch and deleted it to see if it would solve it but it did not.

Comment: you don't seem to link gtest, gtest_main provides only application entry point

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding that now. Still no luck :(.

Comment: What is content of `PROJECT_NAME` variable? Why do you use `${PROJECT_NAME}` for **linking**? You code doesn't define a library with the name `${PROJECT_NAME}`.

Comment: I omitted my main cmake as I wasn't sure if it was relevant? It contains the project definition though. I am pretty new to make but I thought it would give more control so I can easily edit the name later.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your question. In my main cmake I define a shared library with the name "${PROJECT_NAME}" that I want to test in my gtest later.  Looking at it now I could probably just compile it with the test sources as opposed to linking it in. Though with or without that it doesn't change the error.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of research I was able to come right. Just wanted to post an update for anyone running into the same issue. The issue comes from libtorch being compiled in release mode rather than debug causing conflicts with the gtest library. On windows this is easy to solve as torch provides pre-compiled development libraries. However, on linux you will need to compile your own from source and then link it. I used the following guide to get torch compiled for c++ "https://kezunlin.me/post/54e7a3d8/".